# How to know when ngClick fired on an element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following element,

```
<button test-directive>value</button>
```

I know I can use the `ng-click directive`, but then I have to call a function from the controller. When the user clicks, I want to fire a directive called in example `test-directive`

```
testModule.directive('testDirective', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {      }
  }
})
```

how can I implement the ng-click in this directive?

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I got your idea.

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tQLESC?p=preview)

```
directive('testDirective', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace:true,
    template:'<button ng-click="fire()">test</button>',
    controller:function($scope, $element, $attrs){
        $scope.fire = function (){
            console.log("fire !");
        };
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

maxisam answer is correct but

you can use 
`<span test-directive>value</span>` instead of `<button test-directive>value</button>` it will still display button.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WpeglMrDgFOheSVtroeX?p=preview)